# OpenOffice database bike shop

Tags: openoffice-base

[image][image]

I'm designing a bike shop database. I have a problem when first add the client info and add it to the order it creates a OrderID 1, after whenn I enter the Services info I can't add it to the Order because there is already a copy of OrderID 1, how I can update the info in order?

Comment: The error message mentions a duplicate ServiceID, not a duplicate OrderID. Maybe you tried to create a new services entry using the OrderID? What's the exact SQL code you've executed? What's the exact content of the tables Order, Client and Services at that time?

Comment: It sounds like your form lets you enter new types of services into the table "Services", but what you are actually trying to do is select from a list of already-entered services and put the appropriate ServiceID into the table "Order".  I believe this is a problem with form setup, and to make suggestions we'd need to see a copy of the form (maybe post a picture of the form with the Form Navigator window open, or maybe upload a sample copy of the file - with any private information removed - to a file sharing site and include a link in your questions.)